# Make subdivided bone move as one whole bone?

Tags: animation, bones

For the purposes of my game I need bones that would normally be one long bone (arms, legs) to be split into two. The problem with this is that when animating the model the legs and arms now move as if they have three joints (because they do now, but this isn't what I want). Is it possible to have blender ignore the new joint?

Comment: you could animate it as one bone *then* subdivide them/.

Comment: Please upload your .blend file or, at least, a picture of your rig: are the two bones connected? Are they part of a IK chain? do they inherit transforms? etc etc .....